# How to bind checkbox to dto in freemarker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, freemarker

I would like to update a dto with a form.
It works with text fields:

`<@spring.formInput "updateable.name" "" "text"/>` , but I have problem with checkboxes.

The dto has a List and I would like to delete from it roles, or add new roles to it as you check or uncheck the options on the form after submit.

I tried roles with HashMap, and I put all roles into it:

`roles.put(roleDto.getId().toString(), roleDto.getName());`

Form:

```py
<@spring.formCheckboxes path="updateable.roles" options="${roleMap}" separator="<br>"/>
```

Converter:

```py
@Override
public RoleDto convert(final String id) {
  System.out.println("Trying to convert id=" + id + " into a role");
  int parseId = Integer.parseInt(id);
  int index = parseId - 1;
  List<RoleDto> roleDtos = roleApi.fetchAllRoles();
  return roleDtos.get(index);
}
```

The output is:

```
[Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), 
or "template output" , but this has evaluated to an extended_hash 
(wrapper: f.t.SimpleHash):==> roleMap
```

So I don't even see the checkboxes on the form.